# Hide Menu from Previous Fragment when new Fragment is added to the stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

From MainFragment I add `DetailedFragment`. Both `MainFragment` and `DetailedFragment` have their own set of `Menus`. When I add `DetailedFragment` to the stack,how to **hide/show** menu of `MainFragment`.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.activity_main_container, browserFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

I don't want to do replace.